# Only magnify a view itself while using Magnifier in Android

Tags: android, android-magnifier

I am using android native [Magnifier](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Magnifier.Builder) to magnify an imageView. Over this imageView; there is a relativeLayout to show other items on the image. These views have same width and height and has same starting and end points.

When I try to magnify this imageview, magnifier magnify the all the views. I want the magnifier to make only this imageView not over view.

Is that possible?

Comment: Doesn't look like it, even though official docs say that "the magnifier never displays magnified content that does not belong to the view", so that's wrong. I couldn't figure out a workaround for the platform class, but it turns out we can do a specialized magnifier ourselves rather easily, if you don't have to use `Magnifier` specifically. Using basic `Canvas` ops means it works on all API levels, too, and it might make your overlay decoration a little easier: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E1SzdDllZX4tNjw3_RidO7KO3XRhFdK7/view?usp=sharing. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVQTK.gif.

Comment: Slightly better version with elevation: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E2TScFNyJ7gxdL4Uv8z0auaAnGfhPb9Z/view?usp=sharing. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fy7po.gif. I think that's the only other major feature necessary to be able to mimic `Magnifier` pretty much completely, apart from trivial stuff like customizable shape and sizing, and the ability to draw outside of Window bounds. If you really need to draw out of bounds, though, I'm sure we could manage that, too, but it probably won't be quite as simple.

Comment: I think you're working on this =). You are a hero. =) My special aim is this, zooming part is outside of this imageview, another fixed place imageView on the screen. I will look your code. Is your code support this feature?

Comment: Yeah, here's a very quick rework: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E4pozU0wSWCpEDPUNs-YUlTZfMjMK40V/view?usp=sharing. Looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/16vwU.gif. I'll try to clean up that example a bit later on, when I get some free time again. Cheers!

Comment: I was just trying to adjust your code till see your last comment. @MikeM. you are my hero. Last 2-3 days, I was looking for a solution to this situation. And your final work is exactly what I want. I love you =) Please write your code as a solution. All points go to yours. I hope, you have an A+++ day and work. =)

Comment: I tidied that last example and modified it a bit so we don't have to fiddle with coordinating size values for it to work properly. It'll simply make itself an oval in whatever bounds it ends up with. Lemme know if there are any issues with the Kotlin, like some extension not resolving, etc. I can do it in Java too, if preferred. Anyhoo, I don't post answers here atm, so please feel free to finish up this question however you like. You're welcome to quote any of my code or examples, if you decide to post an answer. Thanks for the offer, though. I really appreciate it. Glad I could help. Cheers!